# Selenium automation - unable to locate web element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

hope everyone is well.

I've been trying to automate a form entry by using Selenium. I've used it before and never had an issue with locating the web elements.
I can't seem to locate the form text entry fields as web elements, regardless of the method I use. I tried, XPATH, NAME, CSS SELECTOR, nothing works.

The web page address is

```
https://ee.conifr.com.au/single/9KKQb0af?ref=12_27_32
```

The code I am using is (these are the different options I've tried to locate the first text entry in the form):

```
element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//[@id="aHjEbzEsTogismYtToxncr"]/section[2]/section/label[2]/input')
```

OR

```
element = self.browser.find_element(By.NAME,'/aHjEbzEsTogismYtToxncr/scope1_fuel/unique_vehicle_id')
```

Error msg is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="aHjEbzEsTogismYtToxncr"]/section[2]/section/label[2]/input"}
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Both of the selectors you mentioned above are invalid but the one mentioned in error message is correct and works, still you should avoid using xpaths with indexes and I am assuming you want to enter data into Unique Vehicle ID field, then try this `//span[text()="Unique Vehicle ID"]//following-sibling::input`

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` attribute of the `input` tag contains `unique_vehicle_id`. Have used the same to build Xpath for that element.

```
//input[contains(@name,'unique_vehicle_id')]
```

And need to use some waits, either **Implicit waits** or **Explicit waits** to locate and interact with the element.

1. With **Implicit waits**

```
# Imports required
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://ee.conifr.com.au/single/9KKQb0af?ref=12_27_32")

input1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@name,'unique_vehicle_id')]")
input1.send_keys("unique id")
time.sleep(5) # just to see if the text was entered in the field
```

2. With **Explicit waits**

```
#Imports required for Explicit waits
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://ee.conifr.com.au/single/9KKQb0af?ref=12_27_32")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
input1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@name,'unique_vehicle_id')]")))
input1.send_keys("unique id")
time.sleep(5)
```